# How to use xargs with a command that requires user input?

Tags: pipe, xargs, stdin

I set up a pipe returning the name of a package I'd like to install using `apt-get`:

```
... | xargs -I _ sudo apt install _
```

However, `apt-get` can't read from stdin in this case and exits with:

> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.

I know about the `-y` flag to install the package without user confirmation, but I'd like to actually see the confirmation.

Is there a way to forward the package name to `apt-get` while still allowing it to read from stdin?

Putting `apt-get` on the left side of the whole command is not an option since I don't want `apt-get` to be executed if an ealier command in the pipe is aborted, using the `set -o pipefail` option.

Comment: Would it work if you put the output into an array and then loop over it?

Comment: Using `echo "Please enter something."  | xargs -I _ echo _; read`, I see the output and it requests the read. I don't see how apt would do something else? Or am I assuming something wrong?

Comment: @StefanM In your case, you're running `read` outside the pipe. In the question, `apt` runs inside the pipe. Try something like `echo foo | xargs sh -c "read x; echo $x"`

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, you're right. The ; seperates the  read from the rest. ;)

Comment: @StefanM It would be okay to assign the output of the pipe without the last `apt-get` stage to a variable and then execute `apt-get` on the value of the variable if it is set. Am I correctly assuming that the variable won't be set if the pipe fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pipefail` doesn't stop the right-hand side of the pipeline from running, the whole pipe runs simultaneously, as usual. Try e.g.

```
$ set -o pipefail
$ false | echo foo
foo
```

It's the use of `xargs` that may or may not prevent running `apt` here, if it gets no input. Without `-r` or `-I` it would still run the command at least once.

But you could work around that by capturing the output with a command substitution and then running `apt` or not, based on the result:

```
if packages=$(somecmd...) && [ "$packages" ] ; then
    set -f
    sudo apt install $packages
fi
```

Package names should not have any whitespace, so using `$packages` unquoted should work (assuming the default value of `$IFS`; they probably can't contain glob characters either, so `set -f` may be unnecessary).

Answer (score 2):

With the GNU implementation of `xargs` (the one typically found on systems that also have an `apt` command) and a shell like ksh93/zsh/bash with support for process substitution, you can do:

```
sudo xargs -I _ -ra <(cmd) apt install _
```

instead of:

```
cmd | xargs -I _ sudo apt install _
```

Note that it would probably make more sense to pass all the packages at once to `apt` rather than calling one `apt` per package.

```
sudo xargs -d '\n' -ra <(cmd) apt install
```

(`-d` being another GNU extension)

In any case  like in the pipeline version, with or without `pipefail`, that will run `sudo` regardless of whether `cmd` succeeds or not since `sudo` and `cmd` are started at the same time and run concurrently.